# How to open an browser using the same session in Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: java, session, selenium

I have an application automation framework where the application is actually being treated as a browser. Now, here is my functionality.

Normally it launches the login page always. Now my test case requires that I crash the application first and then relaunch it which will direct to some 'error report' page instead of launching the login page this time.

If I do this from command prompt this functionality works fine because every command prompt window is a session, so basically it crashes and reopens in the same session.

Now this does not work when running through webdriver, because everytime the @BeforeClass runs, it creates a new instance of the application and hence i directs to the login page again instead of directing to the error page.

Any suggestions on how to achieve crashing and repoening the app in the same session would be of great help. I am only providing a small portion of the code from where the driver is being invoked.

```
protected void setupChromeRemoteDriver(String hubUrl, String platformName) throws IOException {

        Platform platform = (platformName != null) ? Platform.valueOf(platformName) : Platform.ANY;

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        capabilities.setBrowserName("chrome");
        capabilities.setPlatform(platform);
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.TAKES_SCREENSHOT, true);

        Set<Cookie> cookies = driver.manage().getCookies();
        for(Cookie cookie : cookies){
            driver.manage().addCookie(cookie);
        }

        driver = new CustomRemoteWebDriver(new URL(hubUrl), capabilities);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Constants.ELEMENT_TIMEOUT_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
```

**CrashApplication.java**

```
public void crashUTAApp(){
        String filePath = Constants.CRASHAPP_BATCHFILE_LOCATION;
        try{
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(filePath); 
            if(null != process && process.waitFor() == 0 && process.exitValue() == 0){
                Reporter.log("App Crashed");
            }else{
                Reporter.log("Failed to crash app");
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible workaround for achieving this is to use @Before annotation inside the test junit class and call CrashApplication from inside it. This way you will have driver started with @BeforeClass and crashing executed inside @Before. Note that if you use this approach, only this scenarios should be covered inside the whole class as @Before is executed before every @Test.
Simple representation of the structure:

(Test Class)

@BeforeClass (create new app instance and call webDriver instance)

@Before (executed before every @Test, calls CrashApplication as precondition for the real @Test)

@Test (will be executed by using the same session and navigate to the Login screen)